# Error in reading DynamoDB record from Spark

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to build a quick report using zeppelin notebook fetching [data from DynamoDB with Apache Spark](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1G4SQRV049UL0/Analyze-Your-Data-on-Amazon-DynamoDB-with-Apache-Spark)

The count is running fine but beyond that I am not able to run anything like

```
orders.take(1).foreach(println)
```

fails with the follwoing error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 5) had a not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, value: )
- field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
- object (class scala.Tuple2, (,{<<A rec from DynamoDB as JSON>>}))
- element of array (index: 0)
- array (class [Lscala.Tuple2;, size 7)
```

How to fix this? I have tries to typecast the results but that failed:

```
 asInstanceOf[Tuple2[Text, DynamoDBItemWritable]
```

so did the filter

```
 orders.filter(_._1 != null)
```

I am planning to convert this to a DataFrame to register this as a temp table. Then I plan to run adhoc queries on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

orders.map(t => t._2.getItem()).collect.foreach(println)

This project can read DynamoDB and create RDD/DataFrame out of it. 
https://github.com/traviscrawford/spark-dynamodb

Answer (score 1):

Im not a complete Spark expert but I know that everything that might be parallelized needs to be Serializable. I think there might be a clue in the error message:

```
object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, value: )
```

A quick check on the definition of that class tells me that it may not be:

```
public class Text
    extends BinaryComparable
    implements WritableComparable<BinaryComparable>
```

This may help:

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-solve-java-io-NotSerializableException-org-apache-hadoop-io-Text-td2650.html

Comment: Hi @haggy, thanks for your response. Here the code reads the dynamoDB table directly as a hadoopRDD. I do not have the option of reading it and then implementing it as a serializable object. I am using the aws provided jars to interact with DynamoDB.